# (Qt) How to check if a QTextEdit widget text was changed from a QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt4, qtextedit, qt-signals

I have a **QTabWidget** parented by a **QMainWindow** that manages **QTextEdit** widgets.

I'd like to know when content was changed in one the tabs and to know which one.
I've been trying to google a solution but after many changed lines in my code and architecture changes of my class.

My last try was:

```
QTextEdit* curr_text_edit = /*slots were used to get this pointer*/;
connect(curr_text_edit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(marquerChangement()));
```

but the slot "marquerChangement()" is never called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If marquerChangement() is not being called, there can only be two possible reasons.  First is that the QTextEdit represented by curr_text_edit never emits a signal (in other words, perhaps you've got the wrong QTextEdit?).

Another possibility is that your call to `connect` failed.  This signal/slot connection is done at runtime, not compile time.  Failures here typically just get printed to stdout, and then the program goes happily on its way.  Check your application output to see if you get a message about a signal or a slot not found.

Comment: I've been checking output but nothing interesting. I've been also playing with isWindowModified() and setWindowModified() but until now, no success. :S

Comment: Then it must be that you've got the wrong curr_text_edit.  If you have access to a debuggable Qt, set a breakpoint where QTextEdit emits that signal, and compare the "this" pointer to the one you have when you connect up the signal.